# how to check and respond when user has selected a dropdown option

Tags: php, angularjs, submit, real-time, ajaxform

I have populated the drop down using php. Now I am trying to show data from database according to what the user selects from drop down list. I know we need to use ajax for this. But I am just curious to know if there is any other way to do it. Using just php? I tried using the following code but it did not worked perfectly. Is there any way to check that user has selected one of the options from drop down,and on the basis run a query to display 
fetched results. like real time fetching. Last option will be to use Angular.js for it. But will that be good to use angular with in a project of php ??

```html
if(isset($_POST[option#])
{ 
//run query to fetch data 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$_POST[option#] - this is the post value from the page request.
You need to pass the value and give a name as:
$.ajax({
  url:..
  data: varname: value
})

this varname need to be the same in your $_POST["varname"]